# RQuantLib FixedRateBondPriceByYield() Non-tradable error

Tags: fixed-income, r, bond, quantlib

How do I use `FixedRateBondPriceByYield()` function on maturity date that is earlier than today? I get "non tradable error" when applying on date older than today.

```
library('RQuantLib')
FixedRateBondPriceByYield(, settlementDays=1, yield = 0.01524, 
                          faceAmount=100,
                          maturityDate = as.Date('2015-07-31'),
                          issueDate = as.Date('2010-07-31'),
                          effectiveDate = as.Date('2010-08-10'),
                          period = 3,
                          rates = 0.0175)

Error in fixedRateBondPriceByYieldEngine(settlementDays, yield, calendar,  : 
  non tradable at September 28th, 2015 (maturity being July 31st, 2015)
```

Note: Changing the maturityDate to a date later than today returns an answer.

Comment: I figured that this works to return an answer `maturityDate = advance('UnitedStates/GovernmentBond', as.Date('2015-07-31'), 10, 3)`